# Detecting a URL in a Django wizard_form.html template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have three SurveyWizardViews all of which use the same standard wizard_form.html which is located at templates/formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html [as per the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)

I have added some basic logic to this template which is designed to detect which page of the form the user is on so that I can include a non standard page/step, this is an image with a JS slider bar underneath. This all works perfectly.

```
{% if wizard.steps.current == '6' %}            
        <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathtwo/" %}{{display_image}}"/>                                                                     
        <section>   
            <span class="tooltip"></span>   
            <div id="slider"></div>  
            <span class="volume"></span>  
        </section>      
{% endif %}
```

However I now want to have a slightly different experience for the user depending on which View/URL they are coming from.

**Question** Is it possible to detect which URL the view is currently using to look at the page? e.g.

```
{% if URL.current == 'www.mywebsite.com/experiment/surveyone/' %}   
    do X


{% if URL.current == 'www.mywebsite.com/experiment/surveytwo/' %}   
    do y
```

I have done some searching but Im not even sure what I'm searching for to be honest. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `request` context variable. Something like:

```
{% if 'experiment/surveyone' in request.path %}
do this
{% endif %}
```

I prefer using `in` instead of `==` to ignore trailing and leading slashes. If you want the whole thing  try the `build_absolute_uri` method. Also check what options does request offer to you (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).

Finally, don't forget to add `django.core.context_processors.request` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (I think it is added by default).